# jQuery animation: Partly reveal div (like opening a drawer)

Tags: jquery, animation, show-hide

I'm comfortable using jQuery to show() a div or make it slideDown() etc but I am struggling to achieve an a particular effect.

On hover over a parent div I'm looking for the child to slide down, as if using

```
$('.divClass').toggle("slide", { direction: "up" }, 500);
```

from the jQuery UI Library. (See in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qh8Ww/1/)).

However, I would like to be able to only reveal a small part of the child div on hover and then slide the rest into view on click.

Setting the css height property of the child div I have rather messily got [this far (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4heX/1/)...

```
$('.hoverDiv').hover(
 function () {
     $('.child').animate({
         height: '25px'
     }, 200);
 });

$('.hoverDiv').click(
 function () {
     var cont = $('.child');
     cont.animate({
         height: '0px'
     }, 200, function () {
         cont.css({
             height: 'auto',
             display: 'none'
         });
         cont.slideDown(200);
     });
 });
```

But I've lost the "sliding drawer" look. Any ideas how to get it back?

Comment: So the bottom of the element should be revealed first instead of the top?

Comment: See my new fiddle. I think the `hover` is the problem because when you animate another element (while still within hover), the element starts based on where it is before the hover. I used a `mouseover/mouseleave`

Comment: Updated to `mouseenter`. It proved to be even better an option, so it doesn't matter if you click the content or the hover bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think something like this will work:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y4heX/3/

```
<div class="hoverDiv">Hover Me
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">see a tiny bit of content. Click to see the rest
            <br>sdf
            <br>asdf</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('.hoverDiv').each(function () {
    var $content = $(this).find('.content').show();

    $content.css("margin-top", -1 * $content.height());
}).hover(function () {
    var $content = $(this).find('.content');

    $content.animate({
        "margin-top": -1 * ($content.height() - 25)
    }, 200);
}, function () {
    var $content = $(this).find('.content');

    $content.animate({
        "margin-top": -1 * $content.height()
    }, 100);
});


$('.hoverDiv').click(function () {
    var cont = $(this).find('.content');
    cont.animate({
        "margin-top" : 0
    }, 200);
});
```

I added a wrapper with `overflow: hidden` and use `margin-top` to hide some portion of the div above the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching your `hover` to a `mouseenter/mouseleave` and adjust your `click` a bit (I used `scrollHeight` for the height):

http://jsfiddle.net/nTn38/4/

**Here's the modified JS:**

```
$('.hoverDiv').mouseenter(function () {
      $(this).find('.content').animate({
          height: '25px'
      }, 200);
}).mouseleave(function () {
      $(this).find('.content').animate({
          height: '0px'
      }, 200);
}).click(function () {
      $(this).find('.content').animate({
          height: $(this).find('.content')[0].scrollHeight
      }, 200);
});
```

Comment: How is blur relevant in this case?

Comment: `mouseover/mouseleave` made it perfect, sorry...check new fiddle

Comment: I hadn't thought of scrollHeight. I like the method - not quite the effect I was looking for, but learnt something new all the same!

Comment: No problem. It was fun to take a shot at!